# How to divide with a loop? (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, primes

I am trying to write a function to determine if a number is prime. I have come up with 
the following solution, however inelegant, but cannot figure out how to write it.

I want to do the following: take the number `x` and divide it by every number that is less than itself. If any solution equals zero, `print 'Not prime.'` If no solution equals zero, print '`Prime.'`

In other words, I want the function to do the following:

```
x % (x - 1) = 
x % (x - 2) =
x % (x - 3) =
x % (x - 4) =
etc...
```

Here is as far as I have been able to get:

```
def prime_num(x):
    p = x - 1
    p = p - 1
    L = (x % (p))
    while p > 0:
        return L
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, jonrsharpe. I know there are a lot of solutions to the problem; however, I am trying to write my own solution in order to learn Python. I still do not quite get how to write a loop or while statement, so I was hoping that by figuring out how to write the the solution I came up with I would incrementally improve my understanding of Python. I appreciate the help. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia provides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Python_implementation) one possible primality check in Python

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n <= 3:
        return n >= 2
    if n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0:
       return False
    for i in range(5, int(n ** 0.5) + 1, 6):
       if n % i == 0 or n % (i + 2) == 0:
           return False
    return True
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, Anti Veeranna. I know there are a lot of solutions to the problem; however, I am trying to write my own solution in order to learn Python. I still do not quite get how to write a loop or while statement, so I was hoping that by figuring out how to write the the solution I came up with, I would incrementally improve my understanding of Python. I appreciate the help. Thanks again!